# Get the id of a selected element in a editable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am making a coding project. It is an online text editor. I want the people to be able to change the color of the element (text) they have selected so I can change the CSS. How should I do that? (Just get the id or whatever of a selected element) I am stuck on how to actually tell which element is being highlighted.
Whenever I try to look it up, All the results are about the `select` element.
Something like `document.getElementByCursor`

[My project](https://texteditorplus.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Please modify your question and add what have you tried so far. What is the problem you are facing.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta okay

Comment: I'm not sure about the effectiveness of that solution,but you would add event listener for each element. So you can add _yourElement.on('click', function(){});_ when new element appear in a DOM.

Comment: @lukbrt I'm interested. could you give more info in an answer?

Comment: @lukbrt isn't there a way to do something like `yourElement.on('click', function(evt){});`

Comment: @lukbrt nevermind

Comment: @EthanZone Coding, Sorry, Of course I meant addEventListener. on method is a jQuery way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this sample will be enough for your needs. You can see here basic solution and upgrade/update for your specific needs. If its good  enough for you please, vote for this answer.

```js
document.getElementById("update_colour").onclick = function() {
  // Get Selection
  sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  }
  // Set design mode to on
  document.designMode = "on";
  if (range) {
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
  
  var dd = document.getElementById("colour_dd");
  var strUser = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
  
  // Colorize text
  document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, strUser);
  // Set design mode to off
  document.designMode = "off";
}
```

```html
<span id="editable_div" contenteditable>
Plaid everyday carry trust fund tofu, twee messenger bag meh cronut waistcoat. Celiac hashtag 90's pour-over literally, hexagon trust fund master cleanse. Fam raclette ramps biodiesel succulents. Squid pork belly coloring book biodiesel cray. Typewriter ugh poutine semiotics thundercats vape, yr YOLO. Distillery stumptown VHS, gentrify knausgaard vegan franzen microdosing chambray forage selvage. Af hell of hammock pabst neutra pour-over tofu fashion axe.
</span>
<br/><br/>
<select id="colour_dd">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>

<button id="update_colour">Update Selected Text Color</button>
```

Comment: ... javascript can do more than I ever dreamed of (: that worked with my modifications: https://texteditorplus.blogspot.com/